# Where firefox stores its ETag data?

Tags: firefox, web, http-headers, etag, http-caching

Does anybody know where Firefox stores ETag data for cahce? I need to delete all ETag data outside the Firefox application and I guess storage could be here: C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

Can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla` is a common location for the network cache.

You can see the specific path that's in use on your system by viewing `about:cache?storage=&context=` (see [About protocol links](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About_protocol_links)) from within Firefox.